# How to make the column header sticky in scroll if my application uses AgGrid and React class based component

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I want to make my column header sticky while scrolling. I am using class based component and AG Grid. I have checked numerous examples but mostly found everyone using function based component. Is there a way to use class based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing different between class based or functional components while using ag-grid and it always has sticky headers under normal usage. just dont forget set the width and height of the grid and it handles the rest of the work.